Unable to send form-data using Salesforce Apex
I am working on Zalo API to get the File token, wrote below code but the API is giving me Status 200 with response body :

{"error":-201,"message":"File not exist!"}

My code:
String fileId = '069HE0000010ZurYAE'; // contentDocumentId
String fileName = 'file-sample_150kB.pdf';
ContentVersion contentVersion = [SELECT Id, ContentSize, Title, ContentDocumentId, VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId = :fileId LIMIT 1];
Blob fileData = contentVersion.VersionData;

String boundary = '----MyBoundary';
String requestBody = '--' + boundary + '\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field1"' + '\r\n' + 
    '--' + boundary + '\r\n' + 
    
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="' + fileName + '"' + '\r\n' + 
    
    'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' + '\r\n' + '\r\n' +
    
    fileData + '\r\n' + 
    
    '--' + boundary + '--' + '\r\n';
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndpoint('https://openapi.zalo.me/v2.0/oa/upload/file');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
req.setHeader('access_token', <access_token_here>);
req.setBody(requestBody);

Http h = new Http();
HttpResponse response = h.send(req);


Hard to tell, if the issue is with what data you are sending (fields/parameter names), or how you are sending it (assembling of the multipart request format.) Can you point to the documentation for this endpoint? Have you tried to make that sense request using a tool like postman?

@C3roe, Yes, I tried this request from Postman and it's working fine. Below is the cURL:
curl --location 'https://openapi.zalo.me/v2.0/oa/upload/file' 
--header 'access_token: <access_token_here>' 
--header 'Accept: application/json' 
--form 'file=@"/C:/Users/Desktop/Sample Files/file-sample_150kB.pdf"'
Link of documentation: https://developers.zalo.me/docs/official-account/tin-nhan/quan-ly-tin-nhan/upload-file

That appears to contain one single parameter named file only. Your request above appears to start with a parameter named field1?

@C3roe I used field1 by reading a blog, I even tried removing it. But still getting: File not exist!
Request body after removing field1:
String requestBody = '--' + boundary + '\r\n' +
'Content-Disposition: form-data;' + '\r\n' +
'--' + boundary + '\r\n' +
'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="' + fileName + '"' + '\r\n' + 

'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' + '\r\n' + '\r\n' +

fileData + '\r\n' + 

'--' + boundary + '--' + '\r\n';


My guess would be that your multipart request is not correctly formed. I'd set up some endpoint myself somewhere, to allows to verify if the data was received correctly or not.
